# HTML5 video in jQuery colorbox

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox

In need to display a local video in HTML5 in a lightbox.

I've tried several method with various results

**1 - Iframe**

The simplest solution and the best one, is this one.

```
<a class="lightboxed" href="media/vid1.mp4">Vid1</a>
<script>
    jQuery('a.lightboxed').colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
</script>
```

But when I do this, I've got 2 white stripe left and right my video (up and down on a mobile screen).
I wan't the lightbox fit the percentage on one dimension and fit the width (or the height) of my video, just like it do with images. But it seems iFrame doesn't have a width or a height.
I'll be fine if I could turn the background color to black, but I don't know how to do.

**2 - Inline**

```
<div style="display:none" id="vid">
  <video autoplay width="80%">
    <source src="media/vid1.mp4 type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
<a class="lightboxed" href="#vid">Vid1</a>
<script>
    jQuery('a.lightboxed').colorbox({inline:true);
</script>
```

Which is worse than the previous version. White background is still there, the content isn't center and my video isn't at the good size.

**So question :**

Is there a better way to achieve lightboxed video ?
Did I misunderstand something, or did I've done something wrong ?

Comment: try this http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#single-youtube

Comment: @yugi, his question was about colorbox and html5 video (mp4) not about youtube and Bootstrap lightbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the background color via CSS:

```
#cboxOverlay {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

To fit iframe video I use this Colorbox options:

```
$('a.colorbox-video').colorbox({
    transition: 'fade',
    rel:'gal',
    width: '80%',
    height: '80%',
    fixed: true,
    iframe: true,
    onLoad: function() {
        $('#cboxClose').addClass('btn btn-sm btn-link').css('color','white');
    },
    onComplete: function() {
        $('#cboxLoadedContent iframe').addClass('iframe-loaded');
    }
});
```

where CSS rules are:

```
.iframe-loaded {
  width:100%;
  height:98%;
}
```